# Use Material Design 2 in Android apps

Tags: android, material-design

Recently most Google apps have been ported to Material Design 2.

See the new [Android Messages redesign](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-messages-enable-material-redesign/).

I would like to use this style in my app; in particular, I really like the new top bar in the home page, the "verbose" floating action button with text and the new font.

Is it possible to include it in an app or is it only for apps made by Google?

Comment: https://material.io/develop/android/

Comment: I've seen that, of course. However most of the stuff there refers to the old Lollipop→Oreo Material Design, not Material 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can include it in your app. you just need to add the following dependency in your app:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
```

You can check out some cool components like Gmail-like chip view, bottom app bar, etc. here:
https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-app-bar/

or you can watch this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SdoddLrywZU

Although it's in kotlin it might serve your purspose.

Comment: It kind of works, but I can't seem to be able to use the new ActionBar design. I'll look into it better tomorrow. Also I see that the Extended FAB, which I wanted to use, is not available yet. Do you know if it's possible to use it anyway?

Comment: Yes,for Extended FAB you might have to wait a little bit as it is in planned status as per official material.io site [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/ExtendedFloatingActionButton.md). And i exactly don't get what you are trying to ask about actionbar design.

Answer (score 1):

Summary of differences is here

https://9to5google.com/2018/04/26/what-is-material-design-2-examples-launch-io/

The only thing you will NOT BE ABLE TO USE is Google's Product Sans font as its closed source. But you should be able to implement everything else however.